# How to connect to a bluetooth device when they are paired?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a class which used to pair and connect to a Bluetooth device. I am using Android 6.0 to implement it. The application has two buttons which are for pair and connection function. It worked well for pair function. However, I cannot implement the connection function. I looked at some example of Bluetooth connection but they are not working when I used in this class. Please look at my class and give me some direction to implement it? Thanks all

[image]

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView mListView;
    private DeviceListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_devices);

        mDeviceList     = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("device.list");

        mListView       = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_paired);

        mAdapter        = new DeviceListAdapter(this);

        mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
        mAdapter.setPairListener(new DeviceListAdapter.OnPairButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {
                BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);

                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    unpairDevice(device);
                } else {
                    showToast("Pairing...");

                    pairDevice(device);
                }
            }

        });
        mAdapter.setConnectListener(new DeviceListAdapter.OnConnectButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectButtonClick(int position) {
            //Connect bluetooth
            }

        });
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mPairReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Connect bluetooth
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                 final int state        = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                 final int prevState    = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                 if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                     showToast("Paired");
                 } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                     showToast("Unpaired");
                 }

                 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Library Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thank A. Omar for useful lib. However, the lib used a fixed UUID. How can I know my UUID from my class?

Comment: As said @user2560571 the UUID is similar to a port number. I **_think_** you can keep it like this...

Comment: Thank you. I found two version of ConnectThread as your code and user2560571. What is more good?

Comment: You're welcome. I quickly searched and it appears you can use a random UUID it will still work... You can generate a random uuid like this: `UUID.randomUUID()`

Answer (score 2):

Connecting as a client is simple. Your first obtain the RFCOMM socket from the desired BluetoothDevice by calling createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(), passing in a UUID, a 128-bit value that you create. The UUID is similar to a port number

if you hold the Bluetooth device from the paired list, you can just use this class to connect to it,

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{
    private BluetoothSocket bTSocket;

    public boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bTDevice, UUID mUUID) {
        BluetoothSocket temp = null;
        try {
            temp = bTDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD","Could not create RFCOMM socket:" + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        try {
            bTSocket.connect();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD","Could not connect: " + e.toString());
            try {
                bTSocket.close();
            } catch(IOException close) {
                Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD", "Could not close connection:" + e.toString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean cancel() {
        try {
            bTSocket.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD","Could not close connection:" + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

i would suggest using this tutorial as a startup point to learn from and know more on how Bluetooth in android works.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-androids-bluetooth-api--cms-24084

Comment: Thank you. I known the class. How can I call it in my class when I click on the Connect buttion. It is performed in the function onConnectButtonClick?